# File can not be deleted when excecuted with camel exec

Tags: java, apache-camel

I have a camel route wich calls

```
<to uri="exec:mediainfo"/>
```

the mediainfo tool https://mediaarea.net/de/MediaInfo

It reads out the metadata from a file.

I noticed that when i try to delte a file after it was touched via mediainfo executed by camel exec sometimes i can not delete it.

When the file is located on local path, there are no problems.

when i call a file from a smb share, the file is only marked as delted but hold from the java.exe process. When i close the java process, the file dissapears suddenly because it is released.

Any idear how to handle this problem?

Comment: Because the file is opened by other process, so it cannot be deleted. Also add exception.

Comment: sorry, what i did not mentioned is that i try to delete it with windows explorer. mediainfo runs only a few secounds, when i try to delete it with windows explorer minutes later the problem is still the same

Comment: Is it possible that MediaInfo is crashing, and never manages to release the lock on the file? I don't think that Java is directly holding on to the file.

Comment: Hey @AdamHawkes, mediaInfo gives back a result that i can use. is there a way to check if its status is crashed ?